# How to chain ML models/pipeline models sequentially?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

***Premise:*** 
I have been working on this ML dataset and I found my ADA boost and SVM to be extremely good when it comes to detecting TP. The confusion matrix for both models is identical shown below.
Here's the image:

[image: SVM Confusion Matrix]

Out of the 10 models I have trained, 2 of them are ADA and SVM. The other 8, some have lower accuracy and others higher by ~+-2%

***MAIN QUESTION:***

How do I chain/pipeline so that all my test cases are handled in the following manner?

1. Pass all the cases through SVM and ADA. If the either SVM or ADA has 80%+ confidence return the result
2. Else, if SVM or ADA don't have a high confidence, have only those test cases evaluated by the other 8 models for a final decision

***Potential Solution:***
My potential attempt involved the use of 2 voting classifiers. One classifier with just ADA and SVM, the second classifier with the other 8 models. But I don't know hot to make this work


Here's the code for my approach:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
ensemble1=VotingClassifier(estimators=[
                                            ('SVM',model[5]),
                                            ('ADA',model[7]),
                                             ], voting='hard').fit(X_train,Y_train)
print('The accuracy for ensembled model is:',ensemble1.score(X_test, Y_test))


#I was trying to make ensemble 1 the "first pass" if it was more than 80% confident in it's decision, return the result
#ELSE, ensemble 2 jumps in to make a decision


ensemble2=VotingClassifier(estimators=[
                                            ('LR',model[0]),
                                            ('DT',model[1]),
                                            ('RFC',model[2]),
                                            ('KNN',model[3]),
                                            ('GBB',model[4]),
                                            ('MLP',model[6]),
                                            ('EXT',model[8]),
                                            ('XG',model[9])
                                             ], voting='hard').fit(X_train,Y_train)


#I don't know how to make these two models work together though.
```

***Extra Questions:***
These questions are to facilitate some extra concerns I had and are NOT the main question:

- Is what I am trying to do worth it?
- Is it normal to have a Confusion matrix with just True Positives and False Positives? Or is this indicative of incorrect training? As seen above in the picture for Model 5.
- Are the accuracies of my models on an individual level considered to be good? The models are predicting likelihood of developing heart disease. Accuracies below:
  [image: All the models]

Sorry for the long post and thanks for all your input and suggestions. I'm new to ML so I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: "*Is what I am trying to do worth it?*" and "*are these considered good?*" are not appropriate questions for SO, which is about *specific coding* issues. Your 2nd bullet does not even contain a question, and the error message is very clear and self-explainable in what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Well those questions were more like a bonus... you don't have to answer them but if you did have time to answer them it would be awesome. The main purpose of this question was to figure out whether you could chain algorithms together.
As far as the code goes, I guess I shouldn't have showed the error but I was trying to show the route I was going down. I'll edit the question again.

Comment: Not good - now you have clearly marked them as "extra questions" (but still no question in the 2nd bullet), but it is not at all clear what you *main* question is!

Comment: You seem to already have realized yourself that a `VotingClassifier` does not provide any kind of *sequential* operation, thus what you are trying to do is definitely not a chain/pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut I made the corrections. And hopefully it's clear, what I'm asking for now. 

If voting classifiers don't work could someone give me a rough example or point me to the resources on how to get this to work?

Comment: Kudos for your responsiveness and willing to improve your post, but I am afraid you are actually not; there is still no clear main **question** (please, get rid of the rhetorics, PS & PPS's), and removing the code was not a good idea - at least it permitted some people to *guess* what your issue is, even if you still don't name it properly and explicitly.

Comment: @desertnaut I have renamed the field to just Main question. It clearly states what my main question. I put the code back in, with comments on my thought process. Got rid of the rhetorics. I hope this is satisfactory.

Comment: unless I'm missing something, yes, your model 5 is fatally flawed. one question, if both ADA & SVM has >80% confidence for some label, but their opinions differ, which model should be prioritized? would taking this decision on the average of their confidences suffice?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan I'm about as sure as you and this is a shot in the dark but I think it depends on the TP and TN values, for example if ADA has higher TP and TN values, you'd pass it thorugh ADA and then SVM. Also an interesting point of note is that the ADA has exactly the same Confusion Matrix as the SVM. This is true because ADA on an underlying level can use a decision tree or SVM. But I'm not sure why their accuracies and Confusion Matrices are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple implementation, that hopefully solves your main problem of chaining multiple estimators:

```
class ChainEstimator(BaseEstimator,ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self,est1,est2):
        self.est1 = est1
        self.est2 = est2

    def fit(self,X,y):
        self.est1.fit(X,y)
        self.est2.fit(X,y)
        return self

    def predict(self,X):
        ans = np.zeros((len(X),)) - 1
        probs = self.est1.predict_proba(X)       #averaging confidence of Ada & SVC
        conf_samples = np.any(probs>=.8,axis=1)  #samples with >80% confidence
        ans[conf_samples] = np.argmax(probs[conf_samples,:],axis=1) #Predicted Classes of confident samples
        if conf_samples.sum()<len(X):            #Use est2 for non-confident samples
            ans[~conf_samples] = self.est2.predict(X[~conf_samples])
        return ans
```

Which you can call like this:

```
est1 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('ada',AdaBoostClassifier()),('svm',SVC(probability=True))],voting='soft')
est2 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('dt',DecisionTreeClassifier()),('knn',KNeighborsClassifier())])
clf = ChainEstimator(est1,est2).fit(X_train,Y_train)
ans = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Now if you want to base your chaining on the performance of `est1`, you can do something like this to record its performance during training, and add a few more `if`s on the `predict` function:

```
def fit(self,X,y):
    self.est1.fit(X,y)
    self.est1_perf = cross_val_score(self.est1,X,y,cv=4,scoring='f1_macro')
    self.est2.fit(X,y)
    self.est2_perf = cross_val_score(self.est2,X,y,cv=4,scoring='f1_macro')
    return self
```

Note that you shouldn't be using simple accuracy for problem like this.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing me with a potential solution and with comments as well. What did you mean by "you shouldn't be using simple accuracy for problem like this."?                          Also, you mentioned earlier that there is likely to be something wrong with my SVM and ADA since they both have the same Confusion Matrices, do you have any idea why?

Comment: When I used ```def fit(self,X,y):
    self.est1.fit(X,y)
    self.est1_perf = cross_val_score(self.est1,X,y,cv=4,scoring='f1_macro')
    self.est2.fit(X,y)
    self.est2_perf = cross_val_score(self.est2,X,y,cv=4,scoring='f1_macro')
    return self
```
I received the following error 3 times:  ```/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1437: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)```

Comment: Because your dataset seems imbalanced, and accuracy can be wildly misleading for this case. f1 is a far better choice. The problem isn't that they have same confusion metric, problem is your matrix doesn't contain true negative. So answer to your second extra question is: no, its not normal

Comment: abt 2nd error, it happens for models with confusion matrix like model 5 & model 7, i.e no label is predicted to belong to neg class. try incorporating [imbalance learning](http://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/) techniques to fight this